# error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a bit of trouble analyzing what is the cause of the error in my code. My code looks fine, and other devs also says its fine:

```
void handle_read_headers(const boost::system::error_code& err, RESTClient::response& resp)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        // Start reading remaining data until EOF.
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::ref(resp)));

    }
}

void handle_read_content(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_transferred, RESTClient::response& resp)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        // Write all of the data that has been read so far.
        std::cout << &response_;

        // Continue reading remaining data until EOF.
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}
```

The whole source code can be found here: http://bit.ly/1gnemqG

The error is this

```
Error   1   error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   HttpClientDemo
Error   2   error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''    C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   HttpClientDemo
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'    C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   HttpClientDemo
Error   4   error C2208: 'boost::_bi::type' : no members defined using this type    C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   HttpClientDemo
Error   5   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   HttpClientDemo
```

What could be wrong in this code?

Comment: which line exactly? post the full error message (if this is excessively large, post it on pastebin and link to it)

Comment: updated the question with the error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within `client::handle_read_content`, the call to `boost::bind` is missing arguments. It should be the same as in `client::handle_read_headers`:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, // this line was missing 
                    boost::ref(resp) // this line was missing 
        )
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to see what is the difference of this code you posted with the code I have there above, can you point out? What was missing?

Comment: @xybrek I added comments to the lines which were missing in `client::handle_read_content`

Comment: It was on the recursive method call X_X